# IPv6, dnsmasq dhcp-range

Tags: ipv6, dnsmasq

I'm trying to assign IPv6 addresses to my LAN clients with dnsmasq 2.62 on Debian Wheezy:

```
enable-ra        
dhcp-range=interface:br0,fde4:709f:bee2:a87b::,fde4:709f:bee2:a87b::ff,ra-stateless
```

The clients are working fine with another IPv6 server, so I guess it's a dnsmasq-issue. The clients get their IPv4 address, but no 6 (only link-local fe80 is shown):

```
dhcp-range=interface:br0,192.168.10.50,192.168.10.150,infinite
```

The dnsmasq logfiles says:

```
Dec 24 00:57:45 strohhalm dnsmasq-dhcp[5561]: stateless DHCPv6 on fde4:709f:bee2:a87b::
Dec 24 00:57:45 strohhalm dnsmasq-dhcp[5561]: SLAAC on fde4:709f:bee2:a87b:: prefix valid 2h
```

Comment: Do you see any router advertisements and router solicitations if you inspect the network traffic?